# jquery.turbolinks not working on $(document).ready in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

After realising my rails app was experiencing the well known issue of `$(document).ready)` not working with turbolinks I installed jquery.turbolinks exactly as the docs suggest but I'm still experiencing the same issue. Whenever turbolinks are used to navigate none of the JavaScript in my `$(document).ready)` function works.

Here is some of my code:

In application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
```

Example of JavaScript not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.notice:empty').hide();
  $('.alert:empty').hide();
  $(".notice").delay(2000).fadeOut();
  $(".alert").delay(2000).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a simple error, I had a small script actually in the application.js file and I didn't realise that `//= require turbolinks` needed to go beneath that too

Answer (score 2):

In this case function will load after turbolinks !

```
function runner(){
  $('.notice:empty').hide();
  $('.alert:empty').hide();
  $(".notice").delay(2000).fadeOut();
  $(".alert").delay(2000).fadeOut();
}
$(runner);
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", runner);
```

Comment: I was under the impression that jquery.turbolinks prevented the need for workarounds like this and allowed you to use `$(document).ready` as normal? At least that's what the docs and other related stackoverflow answers seem to say